# Cassandra WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY incorrect results

Tags: cassandra

I have attempted to reproduce the concept depicted in the section "Using clustering order" as described here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_v3f_vfk_xj__p_sks_qcr_2k

Below is the example borrowed straight from the link:

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries (
  event_type text,
  insertion_time timestamp,
  event blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC);
```

Example insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO timeseries( event_type , insertion_time , event ) 
  VALUES( 'newRow' , dateOf( now() ) , 'bla' );
```

Example query to get the most recent row:

```
SELECT * FROM timeseries WHERE event_type = 'newRow' LIMIT 1;
```

The "LIMIT 1" clause should return the most recently-inserted row, due to the WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY clause defined in the CREATE TABLE statement. However that is not always the case, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

I have some very basic java code that inserts a single row into the table from a main method. I can run it from within eclipse every 5 to 10 seconds, and after just a few launches (each with a single insert), the rows are not returned in the proper order.

I don't have my code sitting in front of me right now, so please forgive me for not being able to cite the exact table structure and queries.

Has anyone else observed this behavior?

BTW - using Cassandra 2.0.9